# In Java, counting linear conflicts of the state of 8 puzzle

Tags: java, heuristics, sliding-tile-puzzle

I need to find linear conflicts of 8 puzzle state, state is represented by int[8], goal state is {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,0}. A linear conflict would be if in a line two tiles that are supposed to be in that line are reversed. Fo example in goal state the first row is 1,2,3 if in the state the first row is 2,1,3 then that is one linear conflict made by tiles 2 and 1.

My code works, but is way too long and awkward. Here it is:

```
public static int linearConflicts(int[] state) {
    ArrayList<Integer> row1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> row2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> row3 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> column1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> column2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> column3 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int[] columnMarkers = new int[] { 0, 3, 6, 1, 4, 7, 2, 5, 8 };
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        if (i < 3) {
            row1.add(state[i]);
            column1.add(state[columnMarkers[i]]);
        } else if (i < 6) {
            row2.add(state[i]);
            column2.add(state[columnMarkers[i]]);
        } else {
            row3.add(state[i]);
            column3.add(state[columnMarkers[i]]);
        }
    }
    return row1Conflicts(row1) + row2Conflicts(row2) + row3Conflicts(row3)
            + column1Conflicts(column1) + column2Conflicts(column2)
            + column3Conflicts(column3);

}

public static int row1Conflicts(ArrayList<Integer> rowState) {
    int conflicts = 0;
    if (rowState.contains(1)) {
        if ((rowState.contains(2))
                && rowState.indexOf(1) > rowState.indexOf(2)) {
            conflicts++;
        }
        if ((rowState.contains(3))
                && rowState.indexOf(1) > rowState.indexOf(3)) {
            conflicts++;
        }

    }
    if (rowState.contains(2) && rowState.contains(3)
            && rowState.indexOf(2) > rowState.indexOf(3))
        conflicts++;
    return conflicts;
}

public static int row2Conflicts(ArrayList<Integer> rowState) {
    int conflicts = 0;
    if (rowState.contains(4)) {
        if ((rowState.contains(5))
                && rowState.indexOf(4) > rowState.indexOf(5)) {
            conflicts++;
        }
        if ((rowState.contains(6))
                && rowState.indexOf(4) > rowState.indexOf(6)) {
            conflicts++;
        }

    }
    if (rowState.contains(5) && rowState.contains(6)
            && rowState.indexOf(5) > rowState.indexOf(6))
        conflicts++;
    return conflicts;
}

public static int row3Conflicts(ArrayList<Integer> rowState) {
    int conflicts = 0;
    if (rowState.contains(7) && rowState.contains(8)
            && rowState.indexOf(7) > rowState.indexOf(8))
        conflicts++;
    return conflicts;
}

public static int column1Conflicts(ArrayList<Integer> columnState) {
    int conflicts = 0;
    if (columnState.contains(1)) {
        if ((columnState.contains(4))
                && columnState.indexOf(1) > columnState.indexOf(4)) {
            conflicts++;
        }
        if ((columnState.contains(7))
                && columnState.indexOf(1) > columnState.indexOf(7)) {
            conflicts++;
        }

    }
    if (columnState.contains(4) && columnState.contains(7)
            && columnState.indexOf(4) > columnState.indexOf(7))
        conflicts++;
    return conflicts;
}

public static int column2Conflicts(ArrayList<Integer> columnState) {
    int conflicts = 0;
    if (columnState.contains(2)) {
        if ((columnState.contains(5))
                && columnState.indexOf(2) > columnState.indexOf(5)) {
            conflicts++;
        }
        if ((columnState.contains(8))
                && columnState.indexOf(2) > columnState.indexOf(8)) {
            conflicts++;
        }

    }
    if (columnState.contains(5) && columnState.contains(8)
            && columnState.indexOf(5) > columnState.indexOf(8))
        conflicts++;
    return conflicts;
}

public static int column3Conflicts(ArrayList<Integer> columnState) {
    int conflicts = 0;
    if (columnState.contains(3) && columnState.contains(6)
            && columnState.indexOf(3) > columnState.indexOf(6))
        conflicts++;
    return conflicts;
}
```

Anyone knows how to do it shorter and less clumsy. If I keep doing methods like this my code will be very hard to read.

Comment: This question would probably be better suited to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What's with all the ArrayLists? I built a 15 puzzle a few years ago and I built it around a matrix of int. Maybe I'm misunderstanding your code, but there's only a couple of states you really care about: 'solved' and 'unsolved,' and the various permutations of 'unsolved' don't matter. How do you know when the puzzle is solved? [0][0] == 1 && [1][0] == 2 && [2][0] = 3 && [3][0] = 4 && [0][1] == 5 and so on. Not sexy, but dead simple.

Comment: To clarify my question about ArrayList: Array Lists should be used when you don't know the number of elements you need at runtime. An 8 puzzle is a three cell by three cell grid by definition. If you have a finite set of elements, you use an array.

Comment: @MarsAtomic. You always have a finite number of elements. OutOfMemoryError was created to ensure this :) Your point is totally valid though. Arrays would be much more suitable here.

Comment: is 3 2 1 also a linear conflict?

Comment: @MadPhysicist maybe *you* have a finite number of elements, but my machine is the magical, black hole powered machine with infinite memory and is always invoked when discussing theory. :D

Comment: 3 2 1 makes 3 linear conflicts (3,2),(2,1),(3,1). I'm using ArrayList to use functions like .contains() and indexOf() no other reason. And I want to get the conflicts not to see if it's solved or unsolved, but to use as a heuristic for an algorithm.

Comment: @MarsAtomic. Ah, one of those. I've been meaning to get one buy they're still too expensive at Best Buy.